# Editing row data not possible with binary primary key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using binary uuids for keys. Is there any way to edit table data with Mysql Workbench for this kind of schema? I end up with:

```
UPDATE `db`.`table` SET `foo`='bar' WHERE `uuid`=?;
```

Which obviously returns an error:

```
ERROR 0: Value not set for all parameters
```

I have no other way to reference the rows I want to edit.

PhpMyAdmin fails at this as well by corrupting all binary data.

edit - to clarify, the actual keys' data type is BINARY(16)

edit 2 - To clarify even more, this question is specifically about MySQL Workbench. I understand prepared statements.

edit 3 - I'm putting a bounty on this in hopes that someone knows a workaround or solution.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of data do you use as `uuid`?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary uuids"? What is the data type of the uuid column? How are you populating it? By "binary uuid" do you mean binary as in raw base-2 values, or binary as in a composite primary key composed of two columns?

Comment: BINARY(16) is the data type. So yes, it's 16 bytes of raw base-2 data generated/populated by my PHP application. This is just a question of convenience, because I don't want to write a script every time I need to edit some rows.

Comment: Then store the UUIDs as a hex string.

Comment: @Greg - u using prepare statement ? do u set the correct type for `?` ?

Comment: @ajreal - I'm using Mysql Workbench, so I'm not sure what you mean. I understand that I can use PDO to run a query and get the right row, but I'm looking for a way to automate this without having to do that.

Comment: @Greg - i never use Workbench before, but use of `?` is for mysql prepare statement. Example http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html , maybe u should posted the full list of SQL that u r running

Comment: @ajreal Thank you, I am familiar with prepared statements and use them exclusively with PDO. My question is about MySQL Workbench, specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could show your table using:

```
SELECT *,HEX(uuid) FROM `db`.`table`;
```

example output:

```
uuid               foo      HEX(uuid)
---------------------------------------------------------------
E��|M_jE��|M_j     test     45ABFA057C4D5F6A45ABFA057C4D5F6A
.
.
```

then you could update it using:

```
UPDATE `db`.`table` SET `foo`='bar' WHERE `uuid`=UNHEX('45ABFA057C4D5F6A45ABFA057C4D5F6A');
```

or

```
UPDATE `db`.`table` SET `foo`='bar' WHERE `uuid`=CAST(0x45ABFA057C4D5F6A45ABFA057C4D5F6A AS BINARY);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any to automate this in Workbench?